# Code Coverage question

Tags: apex, unit-test, code

[image]I saw for the first time in one of my orgs where there is a 29% (61/208) what does that number in the brackets say ?

I have never seen it in any other org. Is this a new release for winter 13 or has this been there forever that I missed?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? After running tests? On the setup screen?

Comment: attached the image where I see the number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the screen shot.

That's the number of lines covered out of total lines in the code (that needs coverage)

The % number has been there for a while, but the # of lines I think is new in winter '13. I don't remember seeing it in the release notes though.

***Edit***
I found it in the release notes:

> **Code Coverage Percentage Details**
>
> The code coverage percentage for a
>   class or trigger displayed on the Apex Classes or the Apex Triggers
>   page includes a fraction between parentheses with the numbers used to
>   compute this percentage, for example, 90% (72/80). The code coverage
>   percentage is calculated by dividing the number of lines covered by
>   tests by the total number of lines that are part of the coverage
>   calculation. Some lines of code are excluded from code coverage
>   calculation, such as:
>
> - Comments
> - System.debug statements
> - Test methods
> - A code statement that is broken up into multiple lines—only the first line is counted
>
> To generate code coverage results, you must run your Apex tests first.
>   If no tests have been run, no code coverage data will exist and 0% (No
>   coverage data) displays for classes (except for test classes) and
>   triggers on the Apex Classes and Apex Triggers pages.